# How to show current user name in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003, worksheet-function

In most of the online resource I can find usually show me how to retrieve this information in VBA. Is there any direct way to get this information in a cell?

For example as simple as `=ENVIRON('User')` (which did not work)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Based on the instructions at the link below, do the following.

In VBA insert a new module and paste in this code:

```
Public Function UserName()
    UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function
```

Call the function using the formula:

```
=Username()
```

Based on instructions at:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

Comment: Thanks! It did not work for me before because I did not create a new module. Now it is all good.

Comment: for anyone coming across this in 2016 the link above does not work

Answer (score 14):

Without VBA macro, you can use this tips to get the username from the path :

```
=MID(INFO("DIRECTORY"),10,LEN(INFO("DIRECTORY"))-LEN(MID(INFO("DIRECTORY"),FIND("\",INFO("DIRECTORY"),10),1000))-LEN("C:\Users\"))
```

Comment: This only works if you save the workbook in your user's directory. At work I save mine on a networked drive, so it shows part of the local IP address.

Answer (score 5):

Example: to view the Windows User Name on Cell C5, you can use this script:

```
Range("C5").Value = ": " & Environ("USERNAME")
```

Answer (score 5):

if you don't want to create a *UDF* in *VBA* or you can't, this could be an alternative.

`=Cell("Filename",A1)` this will give you the full file name, and from this you could get the user name with something like this:

`=Mid(A1,Find("\",A1,4)+1;Find("\";A1;Find("\";A1;4))-2)`

---

*This Formula runs only from a workbook saved earlier.*

*You must start from 4th position because of the first slash from the drive.*

Comment: I like this answer but sadly for documents pulled from the cloud the address does not contain the current user.

Answer (score 5):

This displays the name of the current user:

```
Function Username() As String
    Username = Application.Username
End Function
```

The property `Application.Username` holds the name entered with the installation of MS Office.

Enter this formula in a cell:

```
=Username()
```

Comment: Work at first try, thanks! It returned the full name as "Adam Smith".

Comment: The only real solution - after 5+ years, in a virtual and remote environment gives back my full name.
...where my login name is a 8 digit number, and my home dir is mapped to H:\

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to create a VBA macro that wraps that function, like so:

```
Function UserNameWindows() As String
    UserName = Environ("USERNAME")
End Function
```

Then call it from the cell:

```
=UserNameWindows()
```

See [this article](http://blogs.officezealot.com/charles/archive/2004/12/10/3574.aspx) for more details, and other ways.