# Excel/PowerBi View based on User

Tags: sql-server, excel, gridview, powerbi

At the moment I have a `SqlServer table` with some sales data (including the salesman name) and I want to create tables and graphics that each salesman will be able to check, but just theirs, the users are **domain authenticated**.

My inicial though was creating an `Excel` or `PowerBi` but with my knowledge that would require to create one view and one document for each of the salesman with doesn't seem to be very time effective. (Also, protect the files by filesystem permissions)

I'm aware that with an `ISS` and `asp.net` app I would be able to identify the user and filter the results, that would be *OK* if I was just printing tables, but as I said, I require to have some graphs witch I suppose that would require of even more time (for me) to implement.

Comment: You can use [Row-level security (RLS) with Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-admin-rls/), it's a Pro feature though.

Comment: @NickyvV Yeah it looks like an easy and quick solution, quite unfortunate that is a Pro feature.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptionally:

You could use a cell in Excel that works out the [current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934169/how-to-show-current-user-name-in-a-cell) with a VBA function. This cell can then be read into Power Query [as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989279/how-can-i-reference-a-cells-value-in-a-power-query) and you can use it to filter the query that is returned to the workbook.

Comment: After fighting with Excel (for waay to much time) I managed to make it work, but it's not even properly updating upon opening and only works in excel 2016 (maybe because they embeded the powerquerys). It's a working concept, but it's far from being useful for users.

Comment: If you need it to be compatible with older versions of Excel using the Power Query add-in, then you need to create it in that version.